# Vue.js composable loses reactivity

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity, composable

I'm trying to pass reactive data/a ref (`limit`) into a composable (`useItemsShowing()`).
Whenever I update `limit` by pressing the button, I want the composable to rerun and give me an updated return value.

However, I only get the initial value of the composable. What am I missing?

[Reproduction in Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

#### File *Component.vue*

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, toRef} from 'vue'
import { useItemsShowing } from './useItemsShowing.ts'
  const limit = ref(10)
  const totalCount = 61

  const { itemsShowing, showLoadMoreButton} = useItemsShowing(limit, totalCount)
</script>

<template>
  <p>
    <strong>This should update --></strong> {{itemsShowing}}
  </p>

  <button v-if="showLoadMoreButton" @click="limit += 10">
      {{limit}}
  </button>
</template>
```

#### File *useItemsShowing.ts*

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'

export function useItemsShowing(
  limit = 10,
  totalCount = 0,
) {
  const itemsShowing = ref('Showing 0 out of 0')
  const showLoadMoreButton = ref(true)

  let currentItems = 0

  if (limit.value >= totalCount) {
    currentItems = totalCount
    showLoadMoreButton.value = false
  } else {
    currentItems = limit.value
    showLoadMoreButton.value = true
  }

  itemsShowing.value = `Showing ${currentItems} out of ${totalCount}`

  return {
    itemsShowing,
    showLoadMoreButton,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`watchEffect`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watcheffect) around the code that updates the other `ref`s based on `limit.value`. That code will automatically re-run whenever `limit.value` changes:

```js
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'

export function useItemsShowing(
  limit = 10, 
  totalCount = 0,
) {
  const itemsShowing = ref('Showing 0 out of 0')
  const showLoadMoreButton = ref(true)
  
  let currentItems = 0
     
  watchEffect(() => {
    if (limit.value >= totalCount) {
      currentItems = totalCount
      showLoadMoreButton.value = false
    } else {
      currentItems = limit.value
      showLoadMoreButton.value = true
    }

    itemsShowing.value = `Showing ${currentItems} out of ${totalCount}`
  })
  
  return {
    itemsShowing,
    showLoadMoreButton,
  }
}
```

[demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)